# Python search for file and create output, write content

Tags: python, file, search

I have question about search through directory's for images. If images exists create file, file should have name like (name of directory). Example anka.txt and file should be insade dir.

Example:

```
--LICA
  -Horse
   -img1
    -img1.jpg
    -img2.jpg
   -img2
    -img2.jpg
   -img3
    -img3.jpg
```

How can I search for all images in directory horse and output them into file with these description:
filename = horse.txt and inside horse file content would be like:

```
/LICA/Horse/img1/img1.jpg
/LICA/Horse/img1/img2.jpg
/LICA/Horse/img2/img2.jpg
/LICA/Horse/img3/img4.jpg
```

My code looks like:

```
def create_positive_list():
    try:
        for directory, name, img in os.walk(path):
           for x in img:
                if x.endswith('.jpg'):
                    var_name = directory.split('/') # Split 
                    file_create = open(path+var_name[1]+'/'+var_name[1]+'.txt','w+') # Create file with name in directory

                    #print path+var_name[1]
                    print >> file_create, os.path.join(directory, x)

    except IOError, e:
        print "Error msg: %s"%e


create_positive_list()
```

Comment: What is the problem with what you currently have? Be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter) and [os walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
import os
import fnmatch
path='Your Path'
with open(os.path.join(path,'horse.txt'),'w') as hfile:
    for r, d, fs in os.walk(path):
      for f in fnmatch.filter(fs, '*.jpg'):
          hfile.write(os.path.join(r, f))
          hfile.write(os.linesep)
```

Comment: Thx a lot! Nice and easy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to match the pattern you are looking for.

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('*.jpg')
['my.jpg']
```